# Do spies get damage resistance when cloaked?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

I've noticed often that as a Dead Ringer spy, when I'm cloaked, damage that should kill me instead doesn't, and often I'm left with enough health to get to a nearby health kit.  That being said, is this something in the code I don't know about?

Does being cloaked using any watch give you damage resistance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of the *Gun Mettle Update*, **yes**.

According to the [wiki page](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Gun_Mettle_Update) on the update, the Spy will now receive **20%** damage resistance while invisible regardless of the watch used. He will also receive reduced time on debuffs such as Jarate or Mad Milk while invisible.

As for the Dead Ringer, *two* changes have been made to it in regards to damage:

> [image: Addition] **Changed:** Initial attack that triggers feign death has its damage reduced by 50%
>
> [image: Negative] **Changed:** Damage resistance on triggering feign death scales over time. 65% to 20% over 3 seconds

Another change added in the [Tough Break Update](http://www.teamfortress.com/toughbreak/) means that the damage resistance for the Dead Ringer has been further increased.

> [image: Positive] **Changed:** Initial damage reduction when feigning death increased to 75% from 50%